# Run script in userdata Detached

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, centos, user-data

I am trying to start and run a long running process on my ec2 instance via userdata.

This process needs to stay running for the lifespan of the instance.

This process also needs to run as another user i.e centos and not root.

I am able to run the script and it works fine but it will not allow me to ssh into the server until I stop/start the instance.
Here is how I am running the process now.
I get the error `Connection refused`

`/bin/su -c "/home/centos/downloadAndStart.sh" - centos /dev/null &/dev/null &`

without running the script I am able to ssh into the server as soon as it initializes.

I believe this is because of something like the process is still attached to the PID of the userdata script? Does that make sense?

I am not entirely sure why I cannot ssh into the instance until after I restart the instance.

Comment: Did you check `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` to see whether the User Data script finished executing? You could put an `echo` at the end to check whether it got there.

Comment: Yeah I see the script is making it to the last step; and I believe it must be exiting because the status of the instance gets changed to "Running".

Comment: The `running` status is purely from Amazon EC2 indicating that the instance has been provisioned. It cannot see "into" the instance to know whether the operating system is working correctly.